# Space around text in header elements

Tags: html, css, padding

I have been inspecting a header element using firebug, and have noticed that the header container does not hug its contained text, even though I have no padding set.

```
<h2>test</h2>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BTwk6/

The top and bottom spacing is greater than that on the left and right, the result of this is that my h2 does not sit squarely in its containing box.

Is this normal? Is there anyway to have the h2 box hug its text?

Thanks

Comment: Please post the code relevant to the question. Ideally, **in addition** to the code in the question body itself, please add a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/jquery/1.7.1/) example of your problem. You aren't new here. After 87 questions you should know this.

Comment: @Truth - the code is really quite simple as the questions suggests: <h2>test</h2> i think a jsfiddle may be overkill.

Comment: The point is your CSS really.

Comment: @Truth - None, I tried with several reset style sheets, and in multiple browsers with their defaults. It made no difference to my observations, so I didn't mention it as it was not relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is normal, and things are supposed to be that way. If you e.g. set a border on a heading element, you will see that characters in the heading text will normally not touch the border.

There are two reasons to this. First, the height of a font is a design concept and does not (normally) correspond to the height of any letter; there is empty space above even capital letters as well as below the baseline of text. Descenders like that of “j” or “g” may, in some designs, reach the bottom of the font, and diacritic marks like that of “Ê” may reach the top, or even go beyond it.

Second, there is normally some leading above and below a line, typically a total of 15–20% of the font height. The default depends on the font (and on the browser). In practice, this is meant improve readability and to prevent characters from touching characters on the previous or next line.

The leading is indirectly set by setting `line-height`, since `line-height` sets the total height that is the sum of font height (font size) and leading. By setting `line-height: 1`, you set leading to zero; this is called “setting solid” in typography, and it can be suitable for isolated lines, like a one-line heading. But there is still spacing caused by the first reason mentioned, the spacing that has been “built in” into the font. You can even set `line-height` to a smaller value, like 0.85, making the leading negative. Beware that this may cause vertical truncation of characters if the font used differs from the one you suggest on your page.

Answer (score 2):

Try adjusting the line-height property as well, by default different fonts have different spaces above and below them.  You may not be able to entirely fix this.  For example, the word

```
Tempura
```

Is a whole lot taller than the word

```
mum
```

But the word 'mum' will still have to have the same height above and below the line as 'Tempura'.

Answer (score 0):

by default a h2 element has a margin of 19px top an bottom. Try to reset it

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset margin and padding :

```
h2{margin:0;padding:0}
```

replace 0 with your own values ...

mimiz